# CSS: Truncate table cell and middle the Content

Tags: html, css

i have an Content in an table cell. The content inside is always centered and in the middle. But when the cell is smaller than the Content i want to truncate the Text. But it doesn't work. The Cell has a fixed width and height, but when i truncate it, the cell is to big.
Have anyone an Idea? Or is it possible to use jQuery?

**HTML/CSS**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="">
    <div class="ev orange">
        <div class="ev_text">EURO VI NORM PRODUCT MODIFICATION, M1 LANE KEEPING ASSIST N2 &amp; M2</div>
    </div>
    </a>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>

.ev {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    /* line-height: 28px; */
    position: relative;
    height: 51px;
    display: table;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 8px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.ev_text {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    line-height: 17px;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 51px;
    min-height: 51px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: normal;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
     white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**Here's my fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/vnx0sb2L/1/

Comment: Did you try adding max-width to your .ev_text class? Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vnx0sb2L/4/)

Comment: yes, but i want to show more than one text row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit html structure and css as below.

```
<div class="ev_text">
    <p class="truncate">EURO VI NORM PRODUCT MODIFICATION, M1 LANE KEEPING ASSIST N2 M2</p>
</div>

// css
.truncate{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 51px;
    max-height: 51px;
}
```

The reason of this problem is you have made a div as display: table-cell where ellipsis works with block level element.

You can remove overrride properties from .ev_text class.

Comment: almost perfect, but now I see only the first word in one row. Is it not possible see more than one row. i think the white-space the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/vnx0sb2L/10/

Answer (score 0):

Test like this :

```
<style>
    .ev {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    /* line-height: 28px; */
    position: relative;
    height: 51px;
    /*display: table;*/
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 8px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ev_text {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    line-height: 17px;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 51px;
    min-height: 51px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: normal;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

}
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td style='max-width:12px;height:auto;'>
    <div class="ev orange">
        <div class="ev_text">EURO VI NORM PRODUCT MODIFICATION, M1 LANE KEEPING ASSIST N2 &amp; M2BLALALLALALALLALALLALALALA</div>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The text overflow have to be in .ev no in .ev_text

EDIT :

Also remove in css display table